# Update of RDkit

Tags: updates, python

I installed RDkit following instructions from the following [website](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html) using the following line of code,

```
sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data
```

But when I check the version using the following code (in python), following instructions from this [webpage](https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/message/24425874/)

```
>>> import rdkit
>>> from rdkit import rdBase
>>> rdBase.rdkitVersion
'2013.09.1'
```

I don't get the latest version.

How can I update this version, either in ubuntu at the command line or in python?

System details

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
```

and Ubuntu

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

ps If it is of any interest I want to run a piece of python code called, [take_elementary_step](https://github.com/jensengroup/take_elementary_step)

Comment: Ubuntu repositories don't always have the latest version. The version it has is always the most compatible. That means it should work with the version of Ubuntu you have.

Comment: It works with my Ubuntu but not with the code I'm trying to run.  The author tells me (twitter exchange) that the rdkit version is too low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update RDKit, you'd have to compile it from source.  This doesn't appear to be trivial to do.

This said, I have grabbed the `rdkit` source code from Ubuntu Bionic (in development, but this is the latest from Debian), and backported it within a PPA to Trusty and Xenial.

You can do the following to install the updated version of `python-rdkit` (I am still working on adapting this package to work with the latest RDKit, but I can't guarantee I'll provide ongoing updates):

```
sudo apt-get remove python-rdkit
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teward/python-rdkit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-rdkit
```

While this also will clean out other obsolete packages and such, it should then install a newer version of RDkit (from March 2016).

(I'm still working to see if there's a newer RDKit package somewhere though...)

Comment: Note that I have verified these steps work in a clean environment.  This installs the March 2016 version - the latest available in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

If i search for rdkit with

```
apt search rdkit
```

I get "python-rdkit/xenial 201503-3 amd64" as one of the entries. The version number says 201503-3.

I just tried installing it like you, by running

```
sudo apt install python-rdkit
```

When i import and check the version:

```
>>> rdkit.rdBase.rdkitVersion
'2015.03.1'
```

That is a more recent version than yours atleast, so maybe try reinstalling?

Also notice that this is for python 2.7.12

Comment: You're using Xenial.  OP is on Trusty.

Comment: I got python-rdkit/trusty,now 201309-1 amd64 [installed]
when I ran your code.  When I ran sudo apt install python-rdkit there was no difference with respect to version.

Comment: @user1945827 Note that the answer here was for Xenial, and not Trusty.  You are on Trusty so you have to install via `pip`/PyPI, and not the repositories.  See my answer.

Comment: @ThomasWard when i search via pip i get version 2009: "rdkit (2009.Q1b1)", so im not so sure that that is the answer.

Comment: @mrfred489 I see the same search.  But, when I look at PyPI itself, there's no versions uploaded to PyPI for it.  (And I checked the rdkit site, it's non-trivial to build it since the python part is just a python wrapper around the C libraries that rdkit actually is)